# Factory girl gem generates incorrect line indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

This is an example of factory girl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :camp do
    name "MyString"
    icon "MyString"
url "MyString"
patterns "MyString"
featured_patterns "MyString"
score 1
description "MyString"
end
end
```

It still works but it is a really annoying to fix all the files generated by factory girl. how can i fix this wrong indentation.

Comment: What command are you running to generate that file?

Answer (score -1):

Running rubocop with `--auto-correct` will fix this.

```
rubocop --auto-correct spec/factories/camps.rb

spec/factories/camps.rb:42:1: C: [Corrected] Inconsistent indentation detected.
score 1
^^^^^^^
spec/factories/camps.rb:142:1: C: [Corrected] Extra empty line detected at block body end.

1 file inspected, 2 offenses detected, 2 offenses corrected
```